# Redirect http to https in default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

our site address is like "http://members.XXX.XX", so I want to redirect to the "https://members.XXX.XX" no matter user type "members.XXX.XX" or "http://members.XXX.XX", here is my code, and i put it in the default.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsSecureConnection == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "https://"));
        }

        if (!Request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("http://") || !Request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("https://"))
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.Url.ToString());

        Response.Redirect("~/pages/login.aspx");
    }
```

which doesn't work, anyone can help？ many thanks

Edit:
We didn't do that in IIS because we instored the ELMAH which is a error logging system. My coworker said if we did that the ELMAH wouldn't work

Comment: Why the code above does not work?

Comment: @WiktorZychla have no idea, typed http://members.XXX.XX which didn't redirect to https

Comment: @WiktorZychla I don't have SSL on my computer, but the url do redirect to https://localhost..., and can't display. Mark's method do solve my problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it in code simply let IIS handle it for you.

**IIS7**
Require ssl via IIS and capture the error code `403.4` to do the redirect for you. Step by step guide ["IIS7 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS"](http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html)

**IIS6**
You can create a redirect site that runs on port 80 to handle your redirect to https.  Read more about it ["How to Force Redirection From HTTP to HTTPS on IIS 6.0"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorr/archive/2009/01/13/how-to-force-redirection-from-http-to-https-on-iis-6-0.aspx).

Comment: We tried and my coworker said that will make ELMAH (a error logging system) disabled, so..

Comment: I currently have ELMAH setup and have the redirect in place.  (I am using the basic configuration with elmah)  I simply browse to the site at `https://localhost/elmah.axd` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {

        if (!Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") && !Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
    }
```