# http error code if https only is allowed

Tags: asp.net, http, web, httprequest

I am disabling all http access and want to return an error code to indicate that http is disabled and use https instead.

what is the best error code response for that request?
400 Bad Request
403 Forbidden

Comment: `http 426 "upgrade required" - the client should switch to a different protocol such as tls/1.0, given in the ugprade header field`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: @Marc B can I use http 426 to upgrade to other protocol or an upgrade to a newer version of http?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much value in listening on port 80 unless you're either going to serve up content or point clients to somewhere else.

Either issue a 301 Moved Permanently redirecting to `https` ([Redirect http to https in default.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231668/redirect-http-to-https-in-default-aspx)) or do not listen on port 80.

Comment: i want to listen on port 80 for some other pages but for specific route I want to refuse any http connection

Answer (score -1):

403.4 should be the best, as IIS returns exactly this to client side if HTTPS is required,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891?wa=wsignin1.0